# Probability of a certain permutation

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory

i have the following question: A teacher chooses a student randomly between 44 students and places him at the first place of a line, chooses a second random student from those left and places him second, and so on. If there are 6 students named tami and 4 students named john, what's the probability of at least one student named tami being placed before all the students named john? My approach was $1-P$(all the john's are placed before the tami's). So first i've ordered the john's 4!, then  the tami's 6!, and then the rest are 34 different balls into 11 different urns so that's $34!*CC^{34}_{11}$. All of that divided by all the options 44!, so to conclude it's: $$1-\frac{4!6!34!CC^{34}_{11}}{44!}$$ Is this solution correct? and if so, is there an approach that uses conditional probability formulas?

Comment: The placement of the non-tami, non-john students is irrelevant.  You have a random permutation of the ten relevant student, so the probability that the first is named Tami is $\frac 6{10}$.

Comment: Your complementary event is wrong. The opposite of having at least one tami before all the johns is having at least one john before all the tamis.

Comment: @lulu Thanks, but the question stated "at least one tami", shouldn't i divide it into 6 cases? 1 tami before all johns, 2 tamis... and so on?

Comment: No. Your condition is equivalent to "the first relevant choice is a Tami, not a John."